# What is formula for calculating resistance at different temperatures?

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance

I've read that the formula for determining resistance at different temperatures is :-

$$R_\theta=R_0 (1 +\alpha t)$$

But in my book it is also mentioned that it is used for small temperature change.

So I want to ask, Is there any basic formula for this that can be used for large temperature changes?

Please help me to reach out the answer.

I also got a formula using the above formula

$$R_\theta=R_0 (1 +\alpha t)$$

$$\frac{R_{\theta}}{R_{0}}=1+\alpha t$$

$$\frac{R_{\theta}}{R_{0}}-1=\alpha t$$

$$\frac{R_{\theta}-R_{0}}{R_{0}}=\alpha t$$

Differentiating wrt $t$ gives

$$\frac{d R}{R d t}=\alpha$$

Can we use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, a more general definition of the [temperature coefficient of resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient) is: $$\alpha = \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{d\rho}{dT}$$ where $\rho$ is the resistivity at temperature $T$. Assuming $\alpha$ is constant, you can [integrate the expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient#Mathematical_derivation_of_temperature_coefficient_approximation) to obtain: $$\frac{d\rho}{\rho} = \alpha.dT => \rho = \rho_o e^{\alpha(T-T_o)}$$ where $\rho_o$ is the resistivity at temperature $T_o$. Using the approximation $e^k \approx 1+k$, for small $k$, you will find that this expression reduces to the one you initially wrote.

Technically, this works for larger values of $\alpha \Delta T$, but you must understand that for larger variations of $\Delta T$, the value of $\alpha$ generally does not remain constant. Furthermore, the way you obtained the expression is incorrect. You cannot differentiate an average quantity to obtain it's infinitesimal equivalent.

If you want to obtain equations for resistance, you can use the fact that $R  \propto \rho$, and just replace $\rho$ with $R$

Hope this helps.